# Creating an object placement indicator similar to Apple's focus square

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

Working on my first ARKit project which I use horizontal plane detection to place a 3d model onto the horizontal plane.

I'm trying to use the focus square but as a Swift newbie, I couldn't figure how to use it. So I want to create my own static indicator.

My approach is to create a SCNPlane as an indicator. However, my SCNPlane does not move quickly like Apple's focus square so I need help with my code.

Here's my code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    // Create a SceneKit plane to visualize the node using its position and extent.
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(0.1), height: CGFloat(0.1))
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    plane.materials = [planeMaterial]
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(planeAnchor.center.x, 0, planeAnchor.center.z)

    // SCNPlanes are vertically oriented in their local coordinate space.
    // Rotate it to match the horizontal orientation of the ARPlaneAnchor.
    planeNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)

    // ARKit owns the node corresponding to the anchor, so make the plane a child node.
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as?  ARPlaneAnchor,
        let planeNode = node.childNodes.first,
        let plane = planeNode.geometry as? SCNPlane
        else { return }
    let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
    let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
    let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
}
```

Not sure if this is the right approach? If you guys have the right approach, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it must approximately work this way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    var focusSquare = FocusSquare() // custom class instantiation

    // ............................

    var session: ARSession {
        return sceneView.session
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.session.delegate = self

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(focusSquare)
    }    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        resetTracking()
    } 
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        session.pause()
    }
    func resetTracking() {
        virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject = nil     
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        statusViewController.scheduleMessage("PLEASE, FIND A SURFACE", inSeconds: 5.0, messageType: .planeEstimation)
    }
    func updateFocusSquare(isObjectVisible: Bool) {
        if isObjectVisible {
            focusSquare.hide()
        } else {
            focusSquare.unhide()
            statusViewController.scheduleMessage("MOVE LEFT-RIGHT", inSeconds: 5.0, messageType: .focusSquare)
        }
        if let camera = session.currentFrame?.camera, case .normal = camera.trackingState,
            let result = self.sceneView.smartHitTest(screenCenter) {
            updateQueue.async {
                self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.focusSquare)
                self.focusSquare.state = .detecting(hitTestResult: result, camera: camera)
        }
            addObjectButton.isHidden = false
            statusViewController.cancelScheduledMessage(for: .focusSquare)
        } else {
            updateQueue.async {
                self.focusSquare.state = .initializing
                self.sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(self.focusSquare)
            }
            addObjectButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

You can download Apple's a sample project [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality), where you can see how to create a `FocusSquare()` class.

Comment: Since updateFocusSquare(isObjectVisible) is continuously called  from renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) I cannot understand why it is necessary to add focus square each/several  times: self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.focusSquare).

Comment: Sorry @chiarotto.alessandro, are you talking about Apple's sample code, or I made a mistake in my answer?

Comment: Yes I downloaded Apple sample code too in order to study it. Focus Square is added several times. What I know is that if I add the same node to the  rootNode of the scene the children.count doesn't increase. But I would like understand when a node is removed from the scene by ARKit and why it is necessary to continuously add the same node. You reply is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Apple's focus square smooth behavior is due to the "virtualObjectLoader" class in conjunction with the "updateAtTime" and "didUpdate" implementation of renderer functions

Just give a look to those three elements and you will find the right approach

Please post your code after adding those concepts if any trouble

Comment: Awesome. So my approach of using SCNPlane is acceptable? I will try your suggestion tonight. Thank you.

Comment: Well,  to skip rotation I've used a SCNBox with a very thin height instead (0.01) 

... and for the sake of clarity the "virtualObjectLoader" is part of the Apple's "Handling 3D Interaction" demo

Comment: Gotcha. This is my first time working with ARKit so Apple's sample code is an ancient script to me lol.

Comment: Hi @JoseParedes, may I ask: I've seen VirtualObject implementation but I can't adapt it to my project where I load a model from an external resource. Have you some advice?